# What would be a good time for my modeless form to dispose of itself?

Tags: winforms, idisposable

i have a modeless form. When the user is done with it, and they `Close` it, the form (and its associated resources) are no longer needed.

Correct programming demands that i dispose of anything that implements `IDisposable` (i.e. i cannot wait for a garbage collection to run). This includes myself, a WinForms `Form`.

What is the best or *valid* time for a form to call `Dispose` on itself?

> In "other" languages, you could destroy a form from within the form
>   itself by calling [`Release`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE2/en/Vcl.Forms.TCustomForm.Release):
>
> ```
> void CloseButton(EventArgs e)
> {
>    this.Release();
> }
> ```
>
> This method causes the form to be destroyed after every instance
>   method has returned (and the form has processed all pending messages).
>
> In this "other" language, it would be ***horribly wrong*** to call:
>
> ```
> void CloseButton(EventArgs e)
> {
>    this.Free();
> }
> ```
>
> Because i am then freeing the object that i am running an method on out from under myself; 
>   which causes an access violation momentarily.

i *assume* it dangerously invalid to call:

```
void CloseButton(EventArgs e)
{
    this.Dispose();
}
```

But maybe it's safe to call:

```
void FormClosed(EventArgs e)
{ 
   this.Dispose();
}
```

What's the guidance on a modeless form cleaning up itself when it's no longer needed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out you don't even ***need*** to call `Dispose` on a modeless form. From MSDN:

> ### [Form.Close Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.close.aspx)
>
> When a form is closed, all resources created within the object are
>   closed and the form is disposed. You can prevent the closing of a form
>   at run time by handling the [Closing](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.closing.aspx) event and setting the
>   [Cancel](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.canceleventargs.cancel.aspx) property of the [CancelEventArgs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.canceleventargs.aspx) passed as a parameter
>   to your event handler. If the form you are closing is the startup form
>   of your application, your application ends.
>
> The two conditions when a form is not disposed on **Close** is when:
>
> 1. it is part of a multiple-document interface (MDI) application, and the form is not visible
> 2. you have displayed the form using [ShowDialog](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.showdialog.aspx).
>
> In these cases, you will need to call [Dispose](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.dispose.aspx) manually to mark
>   all of the form's controls for garbage collection.

So to answer my question, *"What would be a good time for my modeless form to dispose of itself?"*

**Answer:** Never